# How to connect domain to another subdomain?

Tags: apache, configuration, subdomain

I have apache server. And I have my own domains:

- `domain.one`
- `sub.domain.one`

And I have another domain `domain.two`

I want, when people get to `domain.two` they will see content from `sub.domain.one`

I need find solution like a parking. **NO redirect of iframe allow**.
When you open `domain.two` it opens `sub.domain.one`

For `domain.two` I made A-record with IP from `sub.domain.one`.
But when visitor opens `domain.two` he see `domain.one` - but I need `sub.domain.one`

I think, at the configs of `domain.one`, I need make some changes, to let server know about customers domains exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I manage it with nginx proxy.

This is a scheme:

1. Domain.com - A-record resolves to your NGINX proxy server.
2. Nginx proxy server make proxy to your subdomain destination.

Nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://sub.domain.com;
        }
}
```